# Copying a struct results in empty struct

Tags: c#, multithreading, struct

### Issue:

I have a weird behaviour in a multithreaded environment: A value in a struct is empty at runtime but contains something when in break mode.

Given the following function:

```
public static double Convert_CurrencyValue(SlimOrderbook orderBook,
    double amountToConvert, bool backward = false)
{
    OrderBookPrice price;
    double result;
    if (!backward)
    {
        price = orderBook.Bids[0];
        result = amountToConvert * price.Price;
    }
    else
    {
        price = orderBook.Asks[0];
        result = amountToConvert / price.Price;
    }
    if (double.IsInfinity(result) || double.IsNaN(result))
    {
        { /* break marker here "/ }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For some reason, sometimes (not always) result will come out infinity.
I added the if statement and a break marker to see what's happening exactly.
In case of the issue, `OrderbookPrice price` equates to the following:

```
double Price: 0;
double ImpliedProfit: 0;
double Volume: 0;
```

At the same time, when in the break marker, `SlimOrderbook orderBook.Asks[0]` equates to something like follows:

```
double Price: 42.5232;
double ImpliedProfit: -0.01;
double Volume: 0.43;
```

This is a screenshot of my debug view:
[image: Screenshot]

### Underlying functions:

The two mainly involved Data structures are `class Orderbook` and `struct SlimOrderbook`

SlimOrderbook:

```
public struct SlimOrderbook
{
    public SlimOrderbook(OrderBookPrice[] asks, double spot, OrderBookPrice[] bids)
    {
        Asks = asks;
        SpotPrice = spot;
        Bids = bids;
    }
    public OrderBookPrice[] Asks { get; private set; }
    public double SpotPrice { get; private set; }
    public OrderBookPrice[] Bids { get; private set; }
}
public struct OrderBookPrice
{
    public double Price;
    public double Volume;
    public double ImpliedProfit;
}
```

SlimOrderbook is beeing generated from within `OrderBook` as a one off working copy which can locally be worked with:

```
public SlimOrderbook GetOrderBook(Currency baseCurrency, Currency quoteCurrency)
{
    if (baseCurrency.Equals(CurrencyPair.BaseCurrency) && quoteCurrency.Equals(CurrencyPair.QuoteCurrency))
    {
        return new SlimOrderbook(asks: (OrderBookPrice[])Asks.Clone(), spot: SpotPrice, bids: (OrderBookPrice[])Bids.Clone());
    }
    else if (baseCurrency.Equals(CurrencyPair.QuoteCurrency) && quoteCurrency.Equals(CurrencyPair.BaseCurrency))
    {
        return new SlimOrderbook(asks: (OrderBookPrice[])InvertedAsks.Clone(), spot: InvertedSpotPrice, bids: (OrderBookPrice[])InvertedBids.Clone());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"BaseCurrency {baseCurrency} or QuoteCurrency{quoteCurrency} does not match Orderbook currencies!");
    }
}
```

### Attempted Fixes:

- I have changed `result = amountToConvert / price.Price;` to `result = amountToConvert / orderBook.Asks[0].Price;` without success.
- I have changed `GetOrderBook()` in order to store an array copy rather than reference in the struct.

Comment: `Asks` is an array, which is not a struct, it's a class, and can absolutely be changed by a different thread holding a reference to it. Note also that even if it was a struct it still might be subject to struct tearing in a multi-threaded situation. Please supply the definition of `SlimOrderbook`

Comment: Can you please give us a [mcve] that we can run ourselves and see the error you're seeing?

Comment: @Charlieface thank you for the suggestion! I now tried to use an array clone of Asks[] unfortunately without success

Comment: If you are writing to the same struct from another thread (you haven't shown that) then weird things will happen. Generally each thread should have their own copy, or you need locking.

Comment: @julianbechtold - Thanks for the extra code, however, it's still not a [mcve]. There are loads of syntax errors. Can you please the complete code?

Comment: reak mode was a typo it should be break mode from visual studio debugging

Comment: @Enigmativity I cannot find Syntax errors. This is actual running code. Compiling fine or to what are you referring with syntax errors?

Comment: Putting mutable structs in a multithreaded setup is just asking for pain. Before even diagnosing this, consider moving to immutable types -- structs are a good start because they're value types, but then also make all the members immutable (`ImmutableList`/`ImmutableArray`). As a bonus all the cloning business becomes superfluous.

Comment: Why is `SlimOrderbook` a struct in the first place? Structs are value types. This means `GetOrderBook` itself returns a *copy* of the new struct. The arrays, the part that actually consumes RAM though are reference types and cloned over and over, resulting in more objects that need garbage collection. Instead of increasing performance (which I suspect why public fields are used), all this causes *worse* performance. Create safe working code first, *then* look into improving performance. A `readonly struct` is both safer and faster than public mutable fields

Comment: @julianbechtold - When I copy the code from your question into a new project it is full of syntax errors. `Currency`, `CurrencyPair`, `Asks`, `SpotPrice`, `Bids`, `InvertedAsks`, `InvertedSpotPrice`, `InvertedBids`, all don't exist. You need to post a [mcve] so that I can at least compile your code.

Comment: @julianbechtold - Please?

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues with the code:

1. As Charlieface mentioned in his first comment, `array` is a reference type, not a value type. This caused updates in the `Orderbook` to reflect in the `SlimOrderbook`
2. Slimorderbook serves the purpose of providing a snapshot/copy of the orderbook for thread local processing. Reference types in struct are still reference types and not copied as value type.

As it turns out, `InvertedAsks` was updated from another thread in a non-atomic  way. `(OrderBookPrice[])InvertedAsks.Clone()` hence copied an orderbook currently beeing updated.

The issue can be fixed by first creating a new `OrderBookPrice[]`, updating it and then replacing the reference in `OrderBook`:

```
OrderBookPrice[] newInvertedBids = new OrderBookPrice[Bids.Length];
for (int i = 0;i < Bids.Length;i++)
{
    newInvertedBids[(Bids.Length-1)- i].Price = 1/Bids[i].Price;
    newInvertedBids[(Bids.Length-1)- i].Volume = Bids[i].Volume;
}
InvertedAsks = newInvertedBids;
```

Comment: If you care about performance and thread-safety you should be using readonly and immutable classes, structs and collations. Using a [readonly struct](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/#the-readonly-structs) can result in faster code than public mutable fields